# WCF Soap WSDL not loading all types

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

We have a WCF SOAP service, huge monolith which builds a WSDL about 430kb.  Up until recently, the service contract was the service class

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesHelper))]
public class FunctionalityProviderService : IServiceBehavior
{
    ...
}
```

But we wanted to extend the service to have some GET endpoints for testing service health.  To that end I extracted an interface like so:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "FunctionalityProviderService"]
public class IFunctionalityProviderService
{
    ...
}

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesHelper))]
public class FunctionalityProviderService : IServiceBehavior, IFunctionalityProviderService
{
    ...
}
```

And updated the web.config to match.

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="CustomServiceBehavior" name="MyProject.FunctionalityProviderService">
  <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" contract="MyProject.IFunctionalityProviderService" bindingConfiguration="BinaryHttpBinding" />
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

This service is IIS hosted through a .svc file so no change was needed there.

After doing this and navigating to /FunctionalityProviderService.svc?singleWsdl, the size of the wsdl dropped to 230kb.  Looks like a whole bunch of type definitions are now missing.

I tried looking into whether or not the KnownTypesHelper is being executed on svc.?singleWsdl loads, but I never get a break point.  I'm at a loss as to where to look next.  There doesn't seem to be a rhyme or reason to which classes are missing and which are present.  I've tried to share as much as I can about this, but the projects and dependencies are rather far reaching.

Comment: You moved the [ServiceContract] from the class to the new interface you created. I'm not a WCF expert but by any chance does the WSDL reflect only the operations in this interface now? Did you do a diff between the old and the new WSDL to see what's different?

Comment: Unfortunately a diff between wsdls is extremely difficult as wsdl.exe more/less puts things in whatever order it pleases.  But I did map out the basic "shape" of both, and the major deviation happens when we get to the type definitions.  However, your comment directed me somewhere I hadn't considered.  I may just need to move the ServiceKnownType attribute to the contract interface.  I bet when you hit ?wsdl it doesn't instance the service, just the contract.

Comment: There are tools to diff XMLs as XMLs, not just text. See for example: http://www.stylusstudio.com/xml-diff.html

Comment: The preferred way to create a WCF contract is by using an interface. This contract specifies the collection and structure of messages required to access the operations the service offers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-service-with-a-contract-interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem appears to be that calling .svc?singleWsdl (or ?wsdl) doesn't actually load the service class, only the contract.  Since my KnownType loading was being done on the service class, that bit of metadata was not available for the contract to know it needed them.

Solution was to move the ServiceKnownType attribute to the interface allowed the missing types to be loaded by the contract.

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "FunctionalityProviderService"]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesHelper))]
public class IFunctionalityProviderService
{
    ...
}
```

After moving the attribute, my wsdl file size swung 200kb in the other direction... now I'm too big.  But I think I know why.